# Can anyone help me understand what's wrong with this code?

Tags: c, arrays, function, return

```
int m[1000]; //declaring global array  

int added(int input){
    for(int i=1;i<= input; i++){
        if(i>0 && input % 2) // checking if the numbers are even...
            m[i]= input; //array implementation
        return m[i]; 
    }
}

int main()
{
    for(int j=2;j<54;j++){
        printf("%d",m[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to return array from a function. why isn't it working?
Implemented array in for loop.

Comment: You don't ever actually call your function, is the most obvious thing.

Comment: Maybe you should call `added()`?

Comment: Also missing braces in `added`.

Comment: Where did you made call to function.Why do want to return array when you declared as global.

Comment: You never call `added`... What do you mean by "Implemented array in for loop?"

Comment: `input % 2` evaluats to `true` for *odd* numbers, which seems to contradict the comment.

Comment: The `return` statement in `added` is inside the `for` loop, so it will be hit on the very first iteration if `input >= 1` holds. If `input < 1` holds, `added` has an undefined return value.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour  - Yes but the OP never assigned any value to it. I dont think the requirement was to find if 1000 `0`s are all even or odd.

Comment: @Acme It is not clear to me what the OP is trying to do but it is not correct to say it is *never* initialized, it is just not initialized to values that are very useful to the OP. Which is different from using an uninitialized variable which is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `main` function has a `for loop` iterating on a variable called `j`, but the body of the loop is trying to use an undefined variable called `i`.

Your `main` function also never even calls your `added()` function.

Moreover, your `added()` function is kind of problematic too.

```
int added(int input){
    for(int i=1;i<= input; i++){
        if(i>0 && input % 2) // checking if the numbers are even...
            m[i]= input; //array implementation
        return m[i]; 
    }
}
```

I code in several different languages, so I'm not sure if this is actually an issue here or not, but your `return` statement is within a `for loop`.  In many languages, this won't compile because your `added()` function doesn't have a `return` statement for every possible execution path.  What happens if you send `added()` an argument `<1`?  `added(0)` or any negative `int` will never enter the `for` loop, so `added()` gets to the end of the function without a `return statement`.

Moreover, with your `return` within the `for loop` and outside the `if` statement, you're guaranteed to only return the result of the first `for` loop, so you may as well just do a nested `if` statement or something.

Then there's your `if` statement.  `if(i>0 && input % 2)`.  The `&&` returns `true` when both halves also return `true` (and that's the only time your `if` statement is executed).  In this case, `i>0` returns `true` every time `i` is a non-zero positive integer.  No problem here.  Meanwhile, `input % 2` doesn't return a boolean.  It will return an `int`, and in this case, it will return `0` or `1`.  It will return `0` on even numbers and `1` on odd numbers.  And as it turns out, the integer `0` is evaluated as a `boolean false` here and non-zero integers are evaluated as `boolean true` so this is probably doing the opposite of what you want.  You need to change `input % 2` to `((input % 2) == 0)` probably.

And finally, if `m[]` is declared globably, you don't actually need to `return` anything.  `main()` and `added()` can both see the variable perfectly fine.  You can modify your function to look like this:

```
void added(int input){
    for(int i=1;i<= input; i++){
        if(/*i will always be >0 in this for loop*/(input % 2) == 0)
            m[i]= input; 
    }
    return;
}
```

Then all you have to do is actually call `added()` from main and it will correctly modify the array.

Answer (score 1):

You use `i` in `main` but you meant to use `j`, I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

You never called `added`, you never initialized `int m[1000];` hence by default the entire array has `0` - you are indexing with `i` in `main` instead of `j`. Return is inside the for loop.

Comment: Please note that it is zero initialized because it is `static`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning an array from `added()`, you are returning an element `m[1]` from the array. The function will return `m[1]` at the first iteration of the `for` loop.
At the first iteration of the `for` loop `i = 1`, so `m[1]` will be whatever the `input` is and the function will return `m[1]` at `return m[1]`.

Another problem in `main()`, you are using `m[i]` but `i` is not defined in `main()`.